# XCODE 6 - Label not centralized on different devices

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

Maybe there is an answer on the StackOverflow, but i can find it!

I have created a new project on Xcode 6 (deployment target for iOS 6+). I have created a View Controller on the Storyboard and put a Label on that, but when i run the app on iPhone 6 emulator the label is not centralized, but on iPhone 4S it is!

I have read a lot of people telling that now we need use Auto Layout with Constraints, but I have an old project on my work that works perfectly on iPhone 4S and iPhone 6 (the label's in this old app is centralized).

Please, can anyone help me with this?

Thanks!

Comment: Follow what a lot of people are telling you. Use auto layout.

Comment: Maybe, but if there is another option I need to know everything about that.

Comment: May be you use the iphone 5 or iphone 4s size to run app. In your xib or storyboard , the viewcontroller size is not mapping the real screen size. So when it runs in different device, the result is different .So the best view, change the layout to autolayout use the constraints or size class tech. It will affect all the subview, so you must change all.

Answer (score 0):

Before the auto layout thing `UIView`'s property `autoresizingMask` can help automatically resize itself. So if your `UILabel`'s `autoresizingMask` is `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth` and `NSTextAlignment` is `NSTextAlignmentCenter` the label in the old project may be centralized on both device